# QGIS Calculating sum with filter based on a column from the same layer, using field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a layer with 3 fields: fieldA and fieldB are texts, fieldC are figures

I try to sum fieldC only when "fieldB"= currentrow attribute 'fieldA'.

In the picture below, the sum for the first line should 9 (5+4)

I read several answers on the website but I cannot find the expression using field calculator.

My formula is `sum( "fieldC" , filter:=("fieldB" = attribute($currentfeature , 'fieldA')))`  but it is not working.

[image: attribute table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the variable scope for `sum()` can't handle `fieldB` being evaluated for the entire dataset but having `fieldA` only referring to the current feature.

A workaround is to store the current value of `fieldA` as a seperate variable using `with_variable()` then plugging that into `sum()`.

Example expression below:

```
with_variable('currfieldA',
              "fieldA",
              sum("fieldC",
                  filter:= "fieldB" = @currfieldA))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! This is working perfectly! It is working with static fields, dynamics fields, with features added before or after the use of the formula (as soon as the layer is refreshed after)