# Nested aggregate functions in print layout

Tags: qgis, expression

I have 3 layers on map, State, County, City. I'm trying to create an Atlas based print layout by the State layer, that aggregates population totals in City layer, grouped by the county.

I can easily extract the data by all the cities in a county

```
aggregate(
    'City',
    'sum',
    "Population",
    intersects(@geometry, geometry(@parent))
)
```

Now I'm trying to nest that into the state layer. The best I can come up with is to create an array of the featureid of the counties within the state:

```
aggregate(
    'County',
    'array_agg',
    "geoid",
    within(@geometry, geometry(@parent))
)
```

I then take that array and apply an `array_foreach` to cycle through and run the first aggregate as the expression:

```
array_foreach(
    aggregate(
        'County',
        'array_agg',
        "geoid",
        within(@geometry, geometry(@parent))
    ),
    aggregate(
        'City',
        'sum',
        "Population",
        intersects(
            @geometry,
            geometry(get_feature('County', 'geoid', @element))
        )
    )
)
```

This function does return an array, however all values in the array are equal, and are the sum of the first county in the array.

To further test this, I removed the first `aggregate` function and defined the initial array:

```
array_foreach(
    array('123','124','125'),
    aggregate(
        'City',
        'array_agg',
        "Population",
        intersects(
            @geometry,
            geometry(get_feature('County', 'geoid', @element))
        )
    )
)
```

The result was the same.  Am I missing something on the `for_each` command?  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate your issue with a different dataset. Individually, each aggregate expression works, but in this context the `@element` variable in the `array_foreach()` scope doesn't seem to be recognised in the `aggregate()` scope. Possibly there is some undocumented use for `@element` in `aggregate()` expression definition that conflicts with or overrides the `array_foreach()` definition.

It sounds similar to this issue [QGIS Calculating sum with filter based on a column from the same layer, using field calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442783/qgis-calculating-sum-with-filter-based-on-a-column-from-the-same-layer-using-fi/442785#442785) where aggregate expression scope doesn't always play nice with other expressions.

Except in this instance, you are using values from an array, and whether they're dynamically generated or defined as a static array, the values just don't get fed into `aggregate()`.

---

For now, I would suggest the easiest workaround is to actually calculate the population per County as a separate field in your datasource (even a virtual field, if you can't edit the datasource), and simply refer to that in your atlas layout expression.

I will update this reply if I figure out a way to do it all within an expression.